# glClearColor doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl

I started sdl and opengl course. i have one problem when i try to change background this function doesn't give any results. i use MSVS and Win8.1.
I was trying use various options with parameters. i always have black background. Any ideas what i could do wrong?

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengles2.h>
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

const unsigned int DISP_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int DISP_HEIGHT = 600;

int SDL_main(int argc, char *args[]) {
// ##### FIXME! #####
SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_GLContext context = NULL;

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    SDL_Log("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 10;
}

atexit(SDL_Quit);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK,SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,0);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

window = SDL_CreateWindow("Tut", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, DISP_WIDTH, DISP_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

if (!window) {
    SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "Error","Couldn't create the main window",NULL);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

if (!context) {
    SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "Error", "Couldn't create an OpenGl context", NULL);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

glClearColor(0.5F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.5F);   // this function changes the color
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
bool quit = false;

while (!quit) {
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_WaitEvent(&event) != 0) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            quit = true;
        }
    }

}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: link to the course : [link](https://keasigmadelta.com/store/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/GLES3-and-SDL2-Tutorials.pdf)

Comment: As a gerneal hint use `glGetError()` at least once in your rendering queue to see if things go wrong.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml

Comment: Your program does not do anything past window initialization. Most notably, it doesn't refresh its display, which might be the issue here. Even if your program won't be updating its display often, you must let it refresh the display when it receives a [SDL_WINDOWEVENT](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent). Or you're planning to have it update its display several times per second, in this case you don't need to refresh on SDL_WINDOWEVENT, but until you have implemented rendering in your main loop, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're not swapping buffers at any point in your loop. You must swap buffers after doing all relevant calls, otherwise the display won't update.